# No Module Name 'kivy'

Tags: python, kivy

Ok, here is the deal, I've followed the instructions from 
[kivy home page](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-linux.html#ubuntu-kubuntu-xubuntu-lubuntu-saucy-and-above)

and everything went well. I added the repository by entering this command into the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kivy-team/kivy
```

Then updated it

```
sudo apt-get update
```

And installed kivy on Ubuntu 18.04

```
sudo apt-get install python3-kivy
```

Then I'd run a simple app-code

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.6') # replace with your current kivy version !

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class MyApp(App):
def build(self):
    return Label(text='Hello world')

if __name__ == '__main__':
MyApp().run()
```

And I received this:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/.../Documents/coding/python/kivy_apps/main.py", line 1, in 
>       from kivy.app import App
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy'

I need a little help in getiing this problem solved. Would be appreciate for any help.

Comment: you may have two Pythons installed (ie. Python 2 and Python 3) and it may install kivy for one Python but you use second Python to run code. Check `python -V` (for Python 2) and `python3 -V` (for Python 3). You can also install it with `pip install kivy` (for Python 2) or `pip3 install kivy` (for Python 3) or even `python3 -m pip install kivy` (to make sure you install it for Python 3) and then run script with `python3 script.py`.

Comment: I think if you don't use virtual envs, then you need to run it with ```python3 file.py```

Comment: Maybe you could give this a try, I think it's worth it on the long run
https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

kivy will be installed in any version of python that is less than python==3.7.5

so do make sure you switch to such python and check again..simply type this in the termal

**python3.version**

and try the import statement

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get install python3-pip

pip(3) install kivy