# ModulenotfoundError when trying to import Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Today I was in the process of learning how to build a mobile app using kivy, so I attempted to import kivy to see if it worked using
import kivy
after I installed it in the file location. It resulted in ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy'

I was not expecting an error, I was expecting the 3 [info] outputs seen in Tech With Tims Kivy tutorial. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bMHK6NDVlCM)

I have reviewed [No Module Name 'kivy'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60997021/no-module-name-kivy) as well as other related stack overflow questions but none of the answers have worked.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install kivy through the terminal, using pip install kivy.